# I am doing a program to calculate factorial of a non negative integer but don't know how to pass the input through command line argument in windows

Tags: c++

I am working on a program to calculate **Factorial** of a non negative integer N.I know the logic but don't know how to pass the input through command line argument and i am working on windows platform. Please explain me with an example.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int fact(int );

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"the fact is: "<<fact(n);

}

int fact(int n)
{
    if(n>=1)
    {
        return n*fact(n-1);
    }
    else
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are received as parameters to `main` function. This code will explain

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fact(int n) {
    if (n >= 1)
        return n * fact(n - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}

/*
 * argc - No. of command line arguments passed (including filename)
 * argv - Command line arguments as array of strings (including filename)
 */
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        // Only filename was received as argument
        cout << "No command line args were entered. Please try again.\n";
    }
    else {
        // There is at least one argument present
        int n = atoi(argv[1]);    // convert string to int
        cout << "the fact is: " << fact(n) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See it running on [<kbd>Coliru Viewer</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01324d53807dac47).

Answer (score -2):

This link contains all the information you need:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  
using namespace std;

int fact(int );

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    int n;

    if(argc>=2){
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Please enter a number: ";
        cin>>n;
    }
    cout<<"the fact is: "<<fact(n);

}

int fact(int n)
{
    if(n>=1)
    {
        return n*fact(n-1);
    }
    else
    return  1;

}
```

Comment: maybe the link contains all information needed, but your answer doesnt. Eg what happens to this code when the program is called without commandline parameters?